# Select one record for group with Entity Framework Core method syntax

Tags: entity-framework-core

In Entity Framework Core I need to express the following SQL query by using the *method syntax* instead.

```
select * 
from [Rule] as t1
where 
(
    select count(*)
    from [Rule] as t2
    where t1.ProductID = t2.ProductID
    and t2.Priority > t1.Priority
) = 0
```

The query returns the records with the highest Priority for each ProductID.

Is there a way?

Thanks.

Comment: I would really like to know who and *why* downvoted my question (w/o leaving a comment, BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
var rules = db.Rules.Where(
        a=>db.Rules.Where(
            b => b.ProductId == a.ProductId && b.Priority > a.Priority
            ).Count() == 0
    );
```

if you'd like use Linq syntax :

```
var rules = from a in db.Rules
            where (
                from b in db.Rules
                where a.ProductId == b.ProductId
                    && b.Priority > a.Priority
                select b
            ).Count() == 0
            select a;
```